# PostGIS Batch File generation error

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, sharpmap, shp2pgsql

I am following the link : http://sharpmap-postgis.blogspot.in/
I have successfully setup my database as mentioned in the above link.
I have downloaded and extracted all the source code from the link mentioned above which include 4 folders namely: "Branches", "BuildProcessTemplates", "Tags", "Trunk" in my folder named SharpMap from which I copied all the source code from the trunk folder in my SharpMap folder.
In the second step of Compiling the SharpMap resource in the above link,i have copied all the Npgsql.* files and Mono.Security.dll from npgsql zip files into my SharpMap folder.
In the next step while creating the batch file,I am facing the following error:

```
S1525: Invalid expression term ''
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\Poco\PoIFeature.cs(12,112): error C
S1026: ) expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\Poco\PoIFeature.cs(12,114): error C
S1519: Invalid token '+' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(64,51): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(70,51): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(76,51): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(89,48): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(90,48): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Tests\Features\FeatureTest.cs(91,48): error CS1526
: A new expression requires () or [] after type
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(303,16): error CS1031: Type
        expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(303,17): error CS0443: Syntax
        error, value expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(303,18): error CS1002: ;
        expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(304,17): error CS1519: Invalid
        token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(305,34): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(306,36): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(307,35): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(308,33): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(309,31): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(310,32): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(311,33): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(312,33): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(313,36): error CS1519: Invalid
        token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(315,17): error CS1519: Invalid
        token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(321,26): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(328,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(329,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(330,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(331,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(332,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(333,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(334,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(335,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(336,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(337,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(338,26): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(338,59): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(339,26): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(339,50): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(341,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(342,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(342,36): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(343,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(343,46): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(344,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(344,42): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(345,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(345,44): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(346,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(346,47): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(347,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(349,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(350,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(351,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(351,52): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(352,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(353,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(354,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(355,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(356,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(357,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(358,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(359,17): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(361,26): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(367,23): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(370,36): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(370,98): error CS1003: Syntax
        error, ']' expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(372,21): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(374,50): error CS1001:
        Identifier expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(375,97): error CS1003: Syntax
        error, ']' expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(385,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(404,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(421,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(433,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(445,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(460,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(477,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(492,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(507,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(525,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(537,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(557,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(569,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(579,16): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(586,35): error CS1518: Expected
        class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(593,17): error CS1022: Type or
        namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(375,96): error CS0101: The
        namespace 'SharpMap.Forms' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(370,80): (Location of symbol
        related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(384,32): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(403,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(420,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(432,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(444,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(459,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(476,32): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(491,32): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(506,32): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(524,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(536,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(556,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(568,30): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\MapBox.cs(578,81): error CS0101: The
        namespace '<global namespace' already contains a definition for '?'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\WinFormSamples\Samples\GdalSample.cs(127,134):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(58,96): error CS100
2: ; expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(59,64): error CS151
9: Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(59,76): error CS151
9: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(59,106): error CS15
19: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(59,115): error CS15
19: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(61,17): error CS151
8: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(69,26): error CS151
8: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(69,73): error CS151
8: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(73,17): error CS151
8: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(96,17): error CS151
8: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Forms\WktGeometryCreator.cs(101,1): error CS102
2: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs(25,20): error
CS0101: The namespace 'SharpMap.Properties' already contains a definition for
        'Resources'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\Examples\SharpMap.Using\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs(25
,20): (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Web\Web\UI\Ajax\AjaxMapControl.cs(57,18): error CS
0101: The namespace 'SharpMap.Web.UI.Ajax' already contains a definition for
        'AjaxMapControl'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Web\UI\Ajax\AjaxMapControl.cs(57,18): (Location
        of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Web\Web\UI\Ajax\AjaxMapControlDesigner.cs(29,18):
error CS0101: The namespace 'SharpMap.Web.UI.Ajax' already contains a definition
        for 'AjaxMapControlDesigner'
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.UI\Web\UI\Ajax\AjaxMapControlDesigner.cs(29,18):
        (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Web\Web\Wms\LegacyWmsServer.cs(892,164): error CS0
241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\SharpMap.Web\Web\Wms\LegacyWmsServer.cs(1007,172): error CS
0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Layers\GdiImageLayerTest.cs(15,69): error CS0241:
 Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(35,55): error CS
1031: Type expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(35,100): error C
S1044: Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration
        statement
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(35,103): error C
S1002: ; expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(39,43): error CS
1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(39,47): error CS
1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(41,13): error CS
0116: A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(47,23): error CS
1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Presentation\MapPresenterTest.cs(59,5): error CS1
022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Serialization\ProviderTest.cs(16,61): error CS024
1: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Serialization\SurrogatesTest.cs(34,82): error CS0
241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Serialization\SurrogatesTest.cs(61,82): error CS0
241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
c:\SharpMap\SharpMap\UnitTests\Serialization\ThemeTest.cs(12,100): error CS0241:
 Default parameter specifiers are not permitted

C:\SharpMap\SharpMap\binpause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I dont know what these errors mean as I am following all the steps from the above mentioned link.

Comment: Please someone help me,guide me through this difficulty.

Comment: The current repository is at https://github.com/sharpmap/sharpmap.